# How to impose a formula in excel?

Tags: excel, logic

I'm trying to distinguish between 2 values in a single cell, if any of them contains "cm" or "ft". For suppose if cell A1 contains "cm" then in cell A5 there should be increment of 5 and if cell A1 contains "ft" then there should be increment of 10 in cell A5.

### Hint: wanna use if condition

[image]

Comment: You can strictly enforce it. But you can do something like highlight the cell a certain colour if you it does not match your criteria.  You can use data valaditation for initial input, but once a number is in A5 and you later change from CM to FT or vice versa, it will not take the number away from A5.  The colouring method would highlight in this situation.  Would the colouring be acceptable?

Comment: OK your screen shot has nothing in A5.  Based on your screen shot what do you want to see as output.  Note you have not talked about A2, A3 or A4 yet

Comment: As shown in S.S. Cell A1=10 ft, A2= 20 ft, A3= 30 cm, A4= 10 cm. Now what I want is, if cell contains "ft" then there should be increment of 5 in A5 and  if cell contains "cm" then there should be increment of 10 in A5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In A5 you can use the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cm",A1)),LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)+5,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)+10)
```

It will search for CM.  If it is found, it will take the number and add 5 to it.  If it is not found, then it assumes FT is there and adds +10 to the number.

You did not state it, but if you want the units added back on at the end of the number, add the following to the end of the formula:

```
&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cm",A1))," cm"," ft")
```

Comment: A1 cell contains "10 cm". Now I want to find whether A1 contains cm or not .

Comment: Although this will work for the sample values provided the formula is not robust: Removing the space between value and unit will result in an error and if the unit is neither *cm* nor *ft* the latter will be (wrongly) assumed. Also see my answer for how to work around these problems.

Comment: I was working with the data as presented, and its not "a problem" for the presented data.  Otherwise I would have to worry about cases with yd, m, miles, km parsecs, etc

Comment: That's true, it is unknown what should happen for other units. But nonetheless there should be a defined state that is assumed in those cases instead of arbitrarily defaulting to *ft*. As I said, this works fine for the example values provided and therefore is a good answer to the question, but it also lacks robustness for other values that this formula might be applied to beyond the example values.

Answer (score 2):

```
A5:  =LEFT($A1,FIND(" ",A$1)-1)+MAX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"cm","ft"},A1)) *{5,10})& " " & RIGHT($A1,2)
```

If the formula finds neither "cm" nor "ft" it will return the same as found in the original cell.

If there might not be a `space`, then use this slightly more complicated formula to return the "number":

```
A5: =LOOKUP(E9+307,--LEFT($A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}))+MAX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"cm","ft"},$A1))*{5,10})&" "&RIGHT($A1,2)
```

If there are other variations, please post them exactly by copying and pasting from the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("cm",A1)-1)+5,0) + IFERROR(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("ft",A1)-1)+10,0)
```

It extracts the part before the first occurence of *cm* and *ft* and adds 5 respectively 10.
Since there can be only *cm* XOR *ft* in the cell (not both), to keep the formula simple I just added the results for *cm* and *ft* setting the component that was not found to 0.

Comment: No result :(. it give's "0". Whether it is cm or ft.

Comment: Any errors will be suppressed and replaced by 0 which is intentional to prevent wrong results. So presumably `=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("ft",A1)-1)` returns an error where there should be none; can you please try and report the result? Also please verify if `=SEARCH("ft",A1)` results in an error.

Comment: I initially thought it might be a version issue with IFERROR, but if that were the case, than he would get ?name or the like not 0 as reported